# Custom Table Cell TextField: no index path for table cell being reused Swift Xcode6 Beta 6

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

When displaying using textfields for the first time from a custom table cell Nib, i receive "no index path for table cell being reused" and none of the Textfield delegate methods work but once exiting the textField and entering it again, the error does not display and the delegate methods work.

cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {
        var mailCell: mailTableCell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mailCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as mailTableCell
        var nib: NSArray = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("mailTableCell", owner: nil, options: nil)
        mailCell = nib.objectAtIndex(0) as mailTableCell

        mailCell.textField.delegate = self
        mailCell.textField.tag = 1
        mailCell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero

        return mailCell

    } else if indexPath.row == 1{
        var passCell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("passCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as passwordTableCell
        var nib: NSArray = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("passwordTableCell", owner: nil, options: nil)
        passCell = nib.objectAtIndex(0) as passwordTableCell

        passCell.textField.delegate = self
        passCell.textField.tag = 2
        passCell.textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Go
        passCell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero

        return passCell

    } else {
        var buttonCell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("loginCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as buttonTableCell
        var nib: NSArray = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("buttonTableCell", owner: nil, options: nil)
        buttonCell = nib.objectAtIndex(0) as buttonTableCell

        buttonCell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        buttonCell.label.tag = 3
        buttonCell.indicator.tag = 4

        return buttonCell
    }
```

viewDidLoad:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var mailCell = UINib(nibName: "mailTableCell", bundle: nil)
    var passCell = UINib(nibName: "passwordTableCell", bundle: nil)
    var loginCell = UINib(nibName: "buttonTableCell", bundle: nil)

    tableView!.registerNib(mailCell, forCellReuseIdentifier: "mailCell")
    tableView!.registerNib(passCell, forCellReuseIdentifier: "passCell")
    tableView!.registerNib(loginCell, forCellReuseIdentifier: "loginCell")
    keyboardHidden = true

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardDidShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardDidHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}
```

textFieldShoudBeginEditing:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {
    let mailField = self.tableView.viewWithTag(1) as UITextField
    let passField = self.tableView.viewWithTag(2) as UITextField


    if textField == mailField {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        let mailCell = textField.superview?.superview as mailTableCell
        UIView.transitionWithView(mailCell.icon, duration: 0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromRight, animations: {
            mailCell.icon.highlighted = true
            }, completion: nil)
        })
    }
    if textField == passField {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        let passCell = textField.superview?.superview as passwordTableCell
        UIView.transitionWithView(passCell.icon, duration: 0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromRight, animations: {
            passCell.icon.highlighted = true
            }, completion: nil)
        })
    }
   return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` guarantees to return a cell if you have registered a nib with that identifier. You don't need to manually do `loadNibNamed` after dequeuing. You are dequeuing a cell, assigning it a `var` then manually creating a new cell and overwriting the dequeued cell. That's why you're not reusing the cells.

On a side note, your classes (`mailTableCell`, `passwordTableCell`, ...) should be capitalized because they are classes, not objects.